# Android updating textviews and alignment

Tags: android, textview, updating

I have 2 textviews side by side, one aligned right and one left to keep them together.  The right side is simply a label for the type of measurement given in the left side.  The problem is that when the left TextView is a large number, the two TextView's are side-by-side with no gap in the middle.  But as soon as the left TextView becomes a small number, it becomes spaced apart from the right side.

For example, it might look like this during one cycle:
3000meters

And then like this on the next:
5   meters

I need it to keep them together.  Is there something I can do to achieve this, xml side or code side when updating the view?

edit - okay I had to edit it in wordpad to get it to show correctly in here

```
<TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/maindatabg"> 
            <TableLayout 
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:stretchColumns="*">
            <TableRow>
               <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/spaceValue"
                  android:text="00.0"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                  android:layout_gravity="right"
                  android:textSize="20dip"/>
              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/spaceTypeValue"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:text="meters"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                  android:layout_gravity="left"
                  android:textSize="14dip"/>
          </TableRow>
      </TableLayout>                                                         
</TableRow>
```

Comment: You need to provide some code samples (layout xml) in order to receive answer

Comment: put 2 spaces on the start of each code string

Comment: I was doing that initially but it was still coming out really bad.

Comment: Is it just a part of layout? Why TableRow is a root element instead of TableLayout?

Comment: Yes, there is much more code above that...few more nested tables.  And no, I cannot switch to another form of layout, as this one is highly complex and is laid out very very nice, except for this one bug

Comment: I think you should bring the whole layout here. The only that part looks ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mention android:gravity="right" to android:id="@+id/spaceValue". A sample layout and tested works fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<TableLayout android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:stretchColumns="*">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/spaceValue" android:text="3000"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_gravity="right"  android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="20dip" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/spaceTypeValue"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="meters"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_gravity="left" android:textSize="14dip" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
    </TableRow>
```

Comment: Okay, it is not RelativeLayout, but android:gravity : Specifies how to align the text by the view's x- and/or y-axis when the text is smaller than the view. So, it is not at all related to layout. FYI : I tried it and it works. Check above. Hope this help you.

Comment: gopal thank you very much, that does it!  I didnt know about just gravity, i thought the only option was to use layout_gravity.  Good stuff!

Comment: @Jesse, if my post helped you to resolve your problem, then I will appreciate if you can rate my answer and accept my answer as best answer. Will help me increasing my reputation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After reformatting your code to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:stretchColumns="*" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/spaceValue" android:text="4"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_gravity="right" android:textSize="20dip" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/spaceTypeValue"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="meters"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_gravity="left" android:textSize="14dip" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

both 4meters and 30000meters looks the same way.

Comment: At initial runtime, yes it will work....but when i have the code update from a large number to a small number, the gap remains...

Comment: So, say I have a thread that constantly updates spaceValue, spaceView.setText(space.trim());   A way you could test it is to have a button and every time you click it will decrement from lets say 4 digitis down to 1

Comment: You should inspect TextView value with debugger. It could contain spaces.

Comment: woodshy, there are no spaces, look at the code sample I posted space.trim().  android:gravity="right" did the trick